# Rotating parallel coordinate axis-names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, parallel-coordinates

When using some of the built in visualization tools in Pandas, one that is very helpful for me is the parallel_coordinates visualization. However, since I have around 18 features in the dataframe, the bottom of the parallel_coords plot gets really messy.

**Therefore, I was wondering if anyone knew how to rotate the axis-names to be vertical rather than horizontal as shown here:**

[image: parallel_coordinates example]

I did find a way to use parallel_coords in a [polar set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uhwj.png), creating a radar-chart; while that was helpful for getting the different features to be visible, that solution doesn't quite work since whenever the values are close to 0, it becomes almost impossible to see the curve. Furthermore, doing it with the polar coord frame required me to break from using pandas' dataframe which is part of what made the this method so appealing.

[image: polar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` should be enough. Here is an example with [the “Iris” dataset](https://raw.github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/iris.csv):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import parallel_coordinates

data = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
parallel_coordinates(data, 'Name')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]